# MongoDB add property to document

Tags: mongodb

I have a document which looks like this:

db.MyCollection.find().pretty():

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a859fa11467065c98b1d901"),
"_class" : "com.my.company.dao.domain.MyCollection",
"referenceId" : "5a859f861467065c98b1d8ff",
"date" : ISODate("2018-02-15T14:55:56Z"),
...
"tenant" : DBRef("Tenant", ObjectId("58500aed747a6cddb55ba094"))
}
```

and now I will add a property **myProperty** with value **0.003** to all of the documents of type MyCollection.
Actually I know how to iterate over all the documents:

```
db.MyCollection.find().forEach(function (doc) {
    // I don't know how to add property myProperty with value 0.003
});
```

but I don't know how to add the property myProperty with value 0.003.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run below command in mongo DB,

```
db.MyCollection.update({},{$set : {"myProperty ":0.003 }},false,true)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to update the Mongodb database from the Pymongo (Python), you can use the following:

```
 dbconn.MyCollection.update({},{"$set" : {"myProperty":0.003 }}, multi=True)
```

multi=True will update multiple documents.
{} is the condition and since you are not passing anything all the documents will be updated.